# how do I solve 'erpnext' permission denial error?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

when I run this command 'bench init erpnext && cd erpnext' on terminal I get this error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'erpnext'. So I tried this 'sudo bench init erpnext && cd erpnext' but got the message: You should not run this command as root. I am using this command so I can install ERPnext on my ubuntu.
Please advise.

Comment: This because your account does not have permission to do. You need to run the command with elevated privilege if you have got access to like this `sudo bench init erpnext && cd erpnext`

Comment: I tried this command 'sudo bench init erpnext && cd erpnext' but got this message: You should not run this command as root

Comment: If you have already used the sudo command it should  be portrayed  in your question.

Comment: So shall I try something else?

Comment: I think the issue is raising because some of the files might be owned by some other user instead of frappe.. I think this might solve this issue `chown -R frappe:frappe *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is raising because some of the files might be owned by some other user instead of frappe.. I think this might solve this issue `chown -R frappe:frappe *`